# getting link ng href selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the link from an `<a>` tag this is my code:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="generic-container-wrapper"]') :
    for md in element.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="summary-text"]//*'):
        print(md.text)
```

I want to get the `ng-href`. I tried everything but didn't work.
and below is the HTML from the site...

```
<a ng-href="https://www.investors.com/market-trend/stock-market-today/dow-jones-futures-biden-stimulus-buzz-wanes-stock-market-rally-tesla-stock/" target="_blank" title="Dow Jones Futures: Stock Market Rally Has Healthy Pullback As Biden Stimulus Buzz Wanes; Tesla Model Y China ..." track="['Trending Searches ' + ctrl.currentFeedItemType, 'click', 'article link: ' + subtitles.sanitizedArticleTitle]" bind-html-compile="subtitles.articleTitle" href="https://www.investors.com/market-trend/stock-market-today/dow-jones-futures-biden-stimulus-buzz-wanes-stock-market-rally-tesla-stock/">Dow Jones Futures: Stock Market Rally Has Healthy Pullback As Biden Stimulus Buzz Wanes; Tesla Model Y China ...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add context node to your second XPath. So replace

```
'//div[@class="summary-text"]//*'
```

with

```
'.//div[@class="summary-text"]//*'
```

Then use `get_attribute` method instead of `text` property:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="generic-container-wrapper"]') :
    for md in element.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="summary-text"]//a'):
        print(md.get_attribute('ng-href'))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/igorsilva/PycharmProjects/selenium_pro/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    for md in element.get_attribute('.//div[@class="summary-text"]//a'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @IgorSilva please use code exactly as it is. Code in traceback is not mine